Getting Child component value in Parent
In reactjs, I want to get child component value at parent. Here is my code for parent and child.
child.js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const Child = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({name: ""});
  
  const handleInputTextChange=(e)=> {
    const {name,value}=e.target;
    let newState = {...state};
    newState.name = name;
    setState(newState);
  }

  return(
    <div key="c-div" className="child">
      <input required id="child" name="childname" value={state.name} onChange={(e)=>handleInputTextChange(e)}/>
    </div>
  );
}

parent.js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Child} from './child.js';

export const Parent = () => {
  
  const [names, setnames] = useState([]);
  
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const newNames = [...names];
    newNames[0] = '1st';
    newNames[1] = '2nd';
    setnames(newNames);
  }
  
  return(
    <div key="div1">
      <form name="myformname" id="myformid" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Child />
        <Child />
        <button> Print Child Names </button> 
      </form>
      The first child names are <b>{names[0]}</b> and <b>{names[1]}</b>
    </div>
  );
}

I am finding multiple issues in it.
If I type in textfield of child, its not showing, its showing always childname as value.
My main question in such cases, how can I get the value from child at parent.
I will be more interested to know if I can get value like child1.getName(), child2.getName() kind of function so that I will not have to make use of callbacks or state variable in parent.

You can either use Redux, Recoil or Atom for such task (if you need to use the same variables on multiple other pages)
** OR **
You could declare the state variables on the parent component and use it as props in the child component.


import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const Child = ({names, setnames}) => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  
  const handleInputTextChange=(e)=> {
    setName(e.target.value);
  }
 
  const setTheName = () => {
    const temp = names;
    temp.push(name);
    setNames(temp);
  }

  return(
    <div key="c-div" className="child">
      <input required id="child" name="childname" value={state.name} onChange={(e)=>handleInputTextChange(e)}/>
      <button onClick={e => setTheName()}>set name</button>
    </div>
  );
}





import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Child} from './child.js';

export const Parent = () => {
  
  const [names, setnames] = useState([]);
  
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //handle logic
    //the names are already assigned to the 'names' variable
  }
  
  return(
    <div key="div1">
      <form name="myformname" id="myformid" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Child names={names} setnames={setnames}/>
        <Child names={names} setnames={setnames}/>
        <button> Print Child Names </button> 
      </form>
      The first child names are <b>{names[0]}</b> and <b>{names[1]}</b>
    </div>
  );
}




If you are working on a large project I would recommend using Redux or some similar library for maintaining states.


You can not access child component directly from the parent one. For basic use, You can try with forwardRef, which pass ref of child component to parent.
reference for forwardRef
For complex logic, We use context api or any other global state management library.
